# How to find nearest DATE1 that is smaller than DATE2 for every ID in Sheet2 in Excel?

Tags: excel

For every ID in Sheet 2 I would like to find nearest DATE1 that is smaller than DATE2 (DATE3). How can I do this in Excel?

**Sheet 1**

```
ID        | DATE1
----------------------
110966887 | 01-22-2013
110966887 | 08-12-2013
110966887 | 06-16-2014
109984461 | 02-01-2016
109984461 | 04-29-2016
109984461 | 08-23-2016
109984461 | 03-07-2017
168775864 | 11-11-2017
168775864 | 09-23-2018
168775864 | 09-25-2018
```

**Sheet 2**

```
ID        | DATE2      | DATE3
-----------------------------------
110966887 | 09-12-2013 | 08-12-2013
109984461 | 09-09-2017 | 03-07-2017
168775864 | 09-26-2018 | 09-25-2018
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming Specific ID in A2 and specific date in B2 use this formula in C2 copied down

`=AGGREGATE(14,6,Date_Range/(ID_range=A2)/(Date_Range<B2),1)`